# How to reset Unity (3D) 4.2 to "factory settings"?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with Unity, that everything has been reversed. I mean, if the objects' moving axises are not up, right, Z, but down, left, Z for example. If I moving a cube up with the moving axis, it will going down on the game view ...

I don't know why it happened, and now I don't know how to reset it back to the "good" settings.

Comment: You're sure you don't have any transforms further up the hierarchy causing this?

Comment: Can you duplicate this behavior in a new, empty scene? In a new, empty project? If not, it's something to do with the scene/project. I'd bet @Bart is on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you've got all your objects that you've been trying to do this with, or a parent of the objects you're trying to move, rotated 180 degrees on at least one axis, and are trying to move the object in "local" mode.  If this is the case, you'll see a little button up by the transform tools, in the editor, that says "local."  Click that so it says "global."

The other possibility is that you've got the viewport upside down, and just need to rotate around to get everything situated, again...

Unity doesn't just flip its axes, like that.  Those axes -never- change, in global space.  Only in local space.