# How to set up Unity on window 7 to default setting

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a newbie in Unity.I've just set up Unity on my computer and explore it.Now,i want to reset it to default setting.How can i do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "reset it to default setting"? User preferences, project settings, UI layout, etc.

Comment: All of them ! i want to reset it to the state like  the state in the first time i opened Unity.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897929/how-to-reset-unity-3d-4-2-to-factory-settings

Answer (score 1):

From the [official Unity forums](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/43397/how-do-i-reset-settings.html):

Navigate to the **Input Manager** and click `Reset`, as per se:

[image]

To get to the Input Manager you must go to `Edit` > `Project Settings` > `Input Manager`.